# Please explain ruby ARGF behaviour

Tags: ruby, command-line, rake

```
   ARGF.each_with_index do |line, idx|
      print( "[#{idx}] #{line} x: " );
      indent = Indent
         # do stuff
      indent = ""
   end #ARGF e
```

Each line from STDIN is displayed as,

```
   x: [1] W:\sandbox\tmp\for_each\for_each.rake
```

Which is *not good* / ***odd***, if you ask me.

One further unexplained result, the line ...

```
 print( "ab: [#{idx}] #{line} x: " );
```

Displays:

```
x: ab: [1] W:\sandbox\tmp\for_each\for_each.rake
```

I just get weird feelings here.  Three questions, is this a:

1. *HOW* does the "x:" string wind-up at the beginning of each '***line***' the string??!
2. Ruby v1.8.7 bug or my bug?
3. How to fix it?

Help wanted.  I keep looking at this and wonder if I what really dumb thing I did?  Many thanks in advance.

aloha, Will

Comment: Please use "Please", not "Pls".

Comment: Huh, _pls_ is as English as 're', 'OK', 'thx' and 'ta'.  English is my mother and ancestral tongue.  *_lol_* Or, this part of the 1066 calculated campaign to force us to all use French?  Oh wait, '_plait_' an '_plaisure_' (please) are already French.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each_line` does not remove the newlines at the end of the lines, so the strings yielded by `each_line` will contain newlines. `print` on the other hand will not add newlines to the end of strings (if you want that, use `puts`). So `print "hello\nworld:` followed by `print "lala"`, will print

```
hello
world:lala
```

which explains why your output looks the way it does.

To get the output you want, use `line.chomp` instead of `line`, which will remove the newline at the end of `line` and thus prevent your strings from containing a line break before `x:`.

Comment: Thanks ... you posted about 30 seconds after I found it.  At least I feel less lost.

Answer (score 1):

A small sorry here.  I *fergot* about end of line and CR/LF issues on Windows. The solution seems to be:

```
line.chomp!
print( "ab: [#{idx}] #{line}:x\n" );
```

Which prints the line:

```
ab: [1] W:\sandbox\tmp\for_each\for_each.rake x:
```

The remaining trap for young players, is to put your own newline(\n) after the chomp!() method.  One mistake I made with this was thinking 'trim()' not 'chomp()' -- How crazy are I.

Cheers,

> Will

Comment: `print "...\n"` is equivalent to `puts "..."`